# Maven test System.out is not printing to the console

Tags: java, maven, testng

I have test in java-TestNG-Maven configuration and some of them are with prints and scanners, if I run from TestNG I see the outputs but in case of run from Maven I don't see it, what do I need to change in order to see it in my console real time?
my testNG.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite">

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="utilities.listeners"/>
</listeners>
    <test name="app installed - test waze">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="test Waze in app"/>
        </run>
    </groups>

    <classes>
        <class name="tests.IOSMainRunner"/>
    </classes>
</test>
```

my POM.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>IntelijWorkSpace</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.java.version>1.8</project.java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.4.0</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
        <version>2.14.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemPropertyVariables>

                </systemPropertyVariables>

                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>IOS.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and one test for example:

```
@Test(priority = 25, groups = {"test Waze in app"}, description = "open main screen and select passengger")
public void testWazeInpassenger() throws InterruptedException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please select Passenger and press 1");
    int input = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Your input was: " + input);
```